# symfony2: Generate an extended category entity with customizable form fields

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

So I am trying to build this app that has a ticketing system. Each ticket entity is to have a category. This is all fine, but I would like to have separate form fields for each category when filling up a new ticket. Also, I would like to have them configurable. This is what the concept should look like (example):

```
Category1 form: Ticket Form + Amount + Starting Date

Category2 form: Ticket Form + Point of Contact (choice) + etc...
```

So the user chooses a category and the form would change dynamically. I currently have it setup where each category is a separate entity, and there is a form listener which adds a sub-form of the appropriate category depending on what the user chooses. The problem is that all of this is hard coded. I would like to have some sort of tool that can edit/add/remove categories and their form fields. For example, I would like to one day add an "Amount" field to Category2.

I don't have much of an idea on how to do this, without generating separate entities for each category. I was thinking of having one entity called TicketCategory with fields like Custom1, Custom2, Custom3... which represent the different form fields to be defined in some configuration file. The problem is with the field types. I would have a big mixture of dates/numbers/strings/etc...

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to even tackle this idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an application where referees can sign up for different tournaments.  For each tournament I need to ask a different set of questions.  So I moved the questions into a yaml file and added enough information such that I could create the form elements dynamically.  So basically I would have:

```
# tourn.yml
tourns:

     opencup:
         desc:    "USSF Open Cup 2013 - Decatur, Alabama - April 12, 13, 14"

         plan:
             lodgingNights:
                     Fri:
                         type:      radio
                         label:     Lodging Friday Night
                         date:     '2013-04-12'
                         choices:  [No: No, Yes: Yes]
                         default:   No
                     Sat:
                         type:      radio
                         label:     Lodging Saturday Night
                         date:     '2013-04-13'
                         choices:  [No: No, Yes: Yes]
                         default:   No

             availabilityDays:
                     Fri:
                         type:      select
                         label:     Availability Friday
                         date:     '2013-04-12'
                         default:   None
                         choices:
                             None:     None
                             Evening:  Kickoff 5PM
                             Not Sure: Not Sure
                      etc
```

So the plan array ends up being passed to the plan sub form which in turn creates all the individual form elements.  I then have a single plan entity which just stores all the individual selections in an array database column.  Seems to work okay.

=======================================================================

Comment asked for some more code.  Here is my "dynamic" PlanFormType"

```
class PlanFormType extends AbstractType
{
protected $metaData = null;

public function getName() { return 'cerad_tourn_person_plan'; }

public function setMetaData($data) { $this->metaData = $data; }
public function getMetaData(     ) { return $this->metaData; }

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{   
    $items = $this->getMetaData();

    foreach($items as $name => $item)
    {
        $isChoice = false;

        switch($item['type'])
        {
            case 'radio':
                $isChoice = true;
                $expanded = true;
                $multiple = false;
                $attr = array('class' => 'radio-medium');
                break;

            case 'select':
                $isChoice = true;
                $expanded = false;
                $multiple = false;
                $attr = array();
                break;

            case 'text':

                $attr = array();

                if (isset($item['size'])) $attr['size'] = $item['size'];

                $builder->add($name,'text',array(
                    'label'    => $item['label'],
                    'required' => false,
                    'attr'     => $attr,
                ));
                break;

        }
        if ($isChoice) 
        {
            $builder->add($name,'choice',array(
                'label'       => $item['label'],
                'required'    => false,
                'empty_value' => false,
                'choices'     => $item['choices'],
                'expanded'    => $expanded,
                'multiple'    => $multiple,
                'attr'        => $attr,
            ));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to post some more of the code? This is really helpful. I am trying to figure out how to save it in the controller. I have my form for the ticket entity, but would like to have this as a sub-form.